# Pull down a message thread in a pgf sequence diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-umlsd

Is it possible to somehow hack the sequence diagram to extend the thread of the received message on `Some Server`, that it will reach down to the next message `notify`?

The code it the following one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\begin{document}
\begin{sequencediagram}%
    \newthread{client}{Some Client}
    \newinst{server}{Some Server}
    \newinst{third}{Some Third Service}
    \begin{call}{client}{do}{server}{}
    \end{call}
    \begin{messcall}{server}{notify}{third}
    \end{messcall}
\end{sequencediagram}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** (regarding the comment from Ignasi)
I would like to have something like the following:

[image]

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Could you sketch what you want? Do you want `notify` appearing inside `do` like `do` appears inside `some client` or `notifiy` starting where `do` finishes ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest hack to achieve something like that is to manipulate the `seqlevel` counter a bit. This counter is part of the what determines how long those rectangles become. If you do

```
\begin{sequencediagram}%
    \newthread{client}{Some Client}
    \newinst{server}{Some Server}
    \newinst{third}{Some Third Service}
    \begin{call}{client}{do}{server}{}
    \addtocounter{seqlevel}{2}
    \end{call}
    \addtocounter{seqlevel}{-2}
    \begin{messcall}{server}{notify}{third}
    \end{messcall}
\end{sequencediagram}
```

you end up with

[image]

which is not exactly what you wanted, but almost.

It is possible to get exactly what you asked for, though I can't say the way I did it is very elegant. I define a new environment `customcall` that does basically the same as the `call` environment does in your case, but has two minor modifications to extend the rectangle in question,  indicated by comments in the code below.

The result of replacing the `call` environment with `customcall`, as defined below, is:

[image: customcall]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\newenvironment*{customcall}[5][1]{
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}
  \stepcounter{callevel} % push
  \path
  (#2)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (cf\thecallevel) {}
  (#4.\threadbias)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (ct\thecallevel) {};

  \draw[->,>=triangle 60] ({cf\thecallevel}) -- (ct\thecallevel)
  node[midway, above] {#3};
  \def\l\thecallevel{#1}
  \def\f\thecallevel{#2}
  \def\t\thecallevel{#4}
  \def\returnvalue{#5}
  \tikzstyle{threadstyle}+=[instcolor#2]
}
{
  \addtocounter{seqlevel}{\l\thecallevel}
  \path
  (\f\thecallevel)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (rf\thecallevel) {}
  (\t\thecallevel.\threadbias)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (rt\thecallevel){}
  ++(0,-2.5cm) node (tmp) {} % this line is new
  ;
  \draw[dashed,->,>=angle 60] ({rt\thecallevel}) -- (rf\thecallevel)
  node[midway, above]{\returnvalue};
  \drawthread{ct\thecallevel}{tmp} % second argument changed to "tmp" from "rt\thecallevel"
  \addtocounter{callevel}{-1} % pop
}

\begin{document}
%Counter manipulation:
\begin{sequencediagram}%
    \newthread{client}{Some Client}
    \newinst{server}{Some Server}
    \newinst{third}{Some Third Service}
    \begin{call}{client}{do}{server}{}
    \addtocounter{seqlevel}{2}
    \end{call}
    \addtocounter{seqlevel}{-2}
    \begin{messcall}{server}{notify}{third}
    \end{messcall}
\end{sequencediagram}%

%Environment hacking:
\begin{sequencediagram}%
    \newthread{client}{Some Client}
    \newinst{server}{Some Server}
    \newinst{third}{Some Third Service}
    \begin{customcall}{client}{do}{server}{}
    \end{customcall}
    \begin{messcall}{server}{notify}{third}
    \end{messcall}
\end{sequencediagram}%
\end{document}
```